# Android: Project structure for opensource projects (GitHub)

Tags: android, android-studio, github, open-source, project-structure

I've mostly been a consumer in the open source world, but now want to start contributing.

Generally the projects hosted on GitHub (Talking about android here) are seen to have the following structure (with a `library` and a `sample` module):

[image]

I was wondering if this structure can be generated using an existing template when creating a new project in **Android Studio**. I intend to put my existing code in the library module and a few samples in the sample module. *I know it is obvious but just stating.*

I tried adding a new project with no activity but it generated a regular android app project with `app` folder. Is there a way to get the structure as seen in screenshot using Android Studio itself, or I'll need to manually add modules as seen?

Comment: You won't get the exact similar structure as GitHub. Open your project in `Android Studio` and you'll see the `project structure` window on the left-hand side. On the top of the same window, Select the `Project` option present in the drop-down menu list. The default selected option will be `Android`. Hope it'll help.